# Running parallel SQL Statements on a table to select unique records in each select

Tags: sql, multithreading, select, databricks

I need to write a sql statement to select unique records from a table. The requirement is that the databricks notebook containing the statement will run on multiple instances and each instance should get unique records
for example if Notebook running on instance 1 has got the results 1-10
then
the second instance should not get the same return results of 1-10, the results should be 11-20 and for third instance 21-30 and so on.
Is there a way to manage the SQL statement in this manner ?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this in parallel? The SQL server is a bottleneck, so it will not go any faster; it will probably be slower. If the purpose is to provide each notebook with a slice of the results, you need some way to order the results and make the results deterministic. We need a more concrete example.

Comment: ther returned results from SQL server are sent down to a service for verification. There are multiple instances of that service running and to speedup the process we need to instantiate multiple processes to get more results in shorter time.There is a limitation on the service end, that it can only take certain number of records per instance therefore we are creating multiple instances to access the same service, so say, in 5 seconds, if single instance returns 1000 results, 10 instances will return 10000 results in the same time. But the source data(SQL table) is the same for all

Comment: There's many ways to approach this, but you probably don't want each thread running its own query; that's difficult to coordinate if the data is changing. In general, you'd have one thread doing the query, fetching results, and then handing off the results as they come in to a pool of workers. The hand-off can be done directly, ie. the query thread spawns the worker pool, or via a queue. Alternatively, each thread queries something like `where id % <number of workers> = 0` so each gets a unique slice of results.